# Nessus install interrupted by WinPcap

Tags: windows-10, installation, wireshark, nmap, winpcap

Why is Nessus installation interrupted by WinPcap? I have a Windows 10 Pro PC with Wireshark and nmap installed, so I know I have WinPcap is already installed, but why is this completely shutting out my Nessus install? it is Nessus version 6.8 64-bit. I don't have a clue why this doesn't offer an alternative, it's the "earlier WinPcap already installed" click OK only, and when I do the Nessus install is canceled. What gives?

Comment: Have you tried asking Tenable?

Answer (score 0):

I just dealt with Tenable on this issue.  For some reason, they want to continue working with an older version of WinPCap.  After nearly an hour of trying different alternatives, we were finally able to upgrade to the latest version oif Nessus professional, but it was painful and I really did not get satisfaction of why they couldn't handle a newer version of winpcap or other alternatives that are now available.

Sigh.

Comment: If you are the same OP you could edit your question or write a comment, other case just use Ask Question

Answer (score 0):

I answer to myself and for information to others:
I just remove Winpcap and Nessus downloaded the compatible version during installation.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall NPCAP if its instaled. Worked for me :)